# Tracking user time

Tags: javascript

I have a website and I want to have a page in this website that measures the time that I've spent on the other pages which means when I am on the shopping segment of my website there is a timer that starts counting and as soon as I get off shopping segment of my website it stops Counting and then I can go to a page that tells me how much time I've been on each segment of my website

This is the code I got from chat GPT but it is lagging with the time which means that 2 seconds IRL is one second in the website and it doesn't actually track the usage of the segments

```
<!-- tracker.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tracker Page</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
        #tracker {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .page {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .page span {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .page .time, .page button {
            width: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .page .time {
            background-color: #3498db;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .page button {
            background-color: #2ecc71;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tracker"></div>
    <button id="shoppingPageButton">Shopping Page</button>
    <button id="aboutPageButton">About Page</button>
    <button id="picturesPageButton">Pictures Page</button>
    <button id="trackerPageButton">Tracker Page</button>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const trackerContainer = document.getElementById('tracker');

            // Initialize or load the tracked data from localStorage
            let trackedPages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('trackedPages')) || {};

            // Create an array of tracked pages
            const pages = ['shopping', 'about', 'pictures', 'tracker'];

            function createResetButton(page) {
                const resetButton = document.createElement('button');
                resetButton.textContent = 'Reset';
                resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => resetTimer(page));
                return resetButton;
            }

            function updateTracker() {
                trackerContainer.innerHTML = '';
                pages.forEach(page => {
                    const pageDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    pageDiv.classList.add('page');

                    const nameSpan = document.createElement('span');
                    nameSpan.textContent = page.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + page.slice(1);

                    const resetButton = createResetButton(page);

                    const timeDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    timeDiv.classList.add('time');
                    timeDiv.textContent = formatTime(trackedPages[page] || 0);

                    pageDiv.appendChild(nameSpan);
                    pageDiv.appendChild(resetButton);
                    pageDiv.appendChild(timeDiv);
                    trackerContainer.appendChild(pageDiv);
                });
            }

            function formatTime(seconds) {
                const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
                const minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
                const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                return `${hours}:${String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(remainingSeconds).padStart(2, '0')}`;
            }

            function resetTimer(page) {
                trackedPages[page] = 0;
                updateTracker();
                localStorage.setItem('trackedPages', JSON.stringify(trackedPages));
            }

            function startTimer(page) {
                trackedPages[page] = trackedPages[page] || 0;
                let startTime = new Date().getTime();

                const timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                    const elapsedMilliseconds = currentTime - startTime;
                    const elapsedSeconds = Math.floor(elapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
                    
                    // Adjusting for potential lag
                    if (elapsedSeconds > 0) {
                        trackedPages[page] += elapsedSeconds;
                        updateTracker();
                        startTime = currentTime;
                        localStorage.setItem('trackedPages', JSON.stringify(trackedPages));
                    }
                }, 1000);

                return timerInterval;
            }

            // Event listeners for page changes
            pages.forEach(page => {
                const pageButton = document.getElementById(`${page}PageButton`);
                let pageTimerInterval;

                pageButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    if (pageTimerInterval) {
                        clearInterval(pageTimerInterval);
                    }
                    pageTimerInterval = startTimer(page);
                });
            });

            // Initial update
            updateTracker();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will not provide home.HTML

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website Time Tracker</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
        header {
            background-color: #3498db;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        header button {
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 8px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #3498db;
            color: #3498db;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <button onclick="location.href='shopping.html'">Shopping</button>
        <button onclick="location.href='pictures.html'">Pictures</button>
        <button onclick="location.href='about.html'">About</button>
        <button onclick="location.href='tracker.html'">Tracker</button>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I mean... have you checked it's accuracy at larger time scales? 2 seconds off could simply be http delay, or the fact that the code is relying on timeouts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is much simpler than what you are doing.

All you need to do is start a timer when the page is done loading and stop the timer when the page is unloaded. The elapsed time can then be stored in `localStorage` for retrieval when needed.

The following code won't work here at Stack Overflow due to sandboxing, but if you try it, you'll see it works.

```js
let startTime = null;
let stopTime = null;

addEventListener("load", function(){
  startTime = new Date();
});

addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
  stopTime = new Date();

  // Store the elapsed time in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("pageCategory", stopTime-startTime);
});

// Then, on the page where you want to retrieve the times, 
// you would (uncomment and) add this:
// let timeAtPageCategory = localStorage.getItem("pageCategory");
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood I have a website with four pages, one of those pages is a Tracker that tracks how much time you've been on every page and displays it which means that when I'm on a certain page the time rest start when I" unload" a certain page the time or has to stop and then update the tracker page accordingly

Comment: @ZACHBerger I'm not sure you understand. If you put this code on each of your pages and set the page category string to a different value for each page, you can then retrieve all the stored times and display them however you wish. This code does exactly what you have described. The "tracker" page isn't what actually tracks the times, they are tracked by the code on each page then those times are stored locally and the elapsed time on the page is then stored for retrieval by the tracker page.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.